# Integral using gamma and beta functions

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, gamma-function, beta-function

I can't solve this, no matter how I try

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{2x}}{4e^{3x}+9}\,dx$$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** You may write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{2x}}{{4e^{3x}+9}}dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{x}}{{4e^{3x}+9}}\times e^{x}dx
= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{u}{{4u^{3}+9}}\,du
\end{align}
$$ then use a [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) to evaluate the latter integral or use [the beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) to get $\displaystyle \frac{\pi }{9 \times2^{1/3} \times3^{1/6}}$ as the desired value.

---

Some details concerning the use of the beta function. We make the following change of variable 
$$
v=\frac{9}{{4u^{3}+9}},\quad u=\left(\frac94\right)^{1/3}\left(\frac1v-1\right)^{1/3},\quad du=\left(\frac94\right)^{1/3}\frac13\left(-\frac1{v^2}\right)\left(\frac1v-1\right)^{-2/3}dv
$$ giving

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{2x}}{{4e^{3x}+9}}dx &=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{u}{{4u^{3}+9}}\,du \\\\&= \left(\frac94\right)^{2/3}\frac1{27}\int_0^1 \left(\frac1v-1\right)^{1/3}v\left(\frac1{v^2}\right)\left(\frac1v-1\right)^{-2/3}dv\\\\
> &= \left(\frac94\right)^{2/3}\frac1{27}\int_0^1 v^{1/3-1}\left(1-v\right)^{2/3-1}dv\\\\
> &=\left(\frac94\right)^{2/3}\frac1{27} \times B(1/3,2/3)\\\\
> &=\color{red}{ \frac{\pi }{9 \times2^{1/3} \times3^{1/6}}.}
> \end{align}
> $$